# sqoop user defined functions

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Is apache sqoop 1 or sqoop 2 supports user defined functions ? we have a scenario where the data is in HDFS and want to extract the data elements from the records sitting in HDFS and insert into RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

i doubt Sqoop supports UDF , but you can anytime write a custom mapreduce job to extract data from HDFS at a particular location and use sqoop to to export this to RDBMS, you can also automate this to run atomically by configuring this as a flow in oozie.